# How to get two table's common table using linq

Tags: c#, linq

[image: Data tables]

I want to combine these two linq queries to single query
is it possible?

```
    var chestProducts = (from w in WareHouse
                                   join c in Chests on w.Id equals c.WareHouseId
                                   join p in Products on c.Id equals p.ContainerId                                    
                                   where (p.IsContainerChest == true && w.Id == 1)
                                   select p
            ).ToList();

    var boxProducts = (from w in WareHouse
                                   join b in Boxes on w.Id equals b.WareHouseId
                                   join p in Products on b.Id equals p.ContainerId                                    
                                   where (p.IsContainerChest != true && w.Id == 1)
                                   select p
            ).ToList();

    var allProducts = chestProducts.AddRange(boxProducts);
```

Should I use two queries?

And is this relation is healty?

Edit: Boxes and Chests tables are simplifed they have different fields

Comment: I have several questions before I can answer: 1: i see from your comment you are using entity framework, but what version? 2: are you using code first or DB first? 3: do you have foreign key constraints set up on those tables? 4: are there any real differences between `Box` and `Chest` that you have left out?

Comment: 1 : My Entity Framework version is v6.2.0
2 : I use code first
3 : Yes I have foeign key constraints Chests and Boxes classes have virtual lists of Products.
4 : Chests and Boxes tables must be different tables. I quite simplified them for the question.

Comment: Are you using database first? or code first?

Comment: I'm using code first

Comment: that makes life easier. Are you particularly attached to using the query syntax of linq over the lambda?

Comment: I usually use lambda but I'm not good enough at linq so this problem is a bit confusing to me so I wrote like this

Comment: OK, hold tight, I will have an answer for you soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, from your comments I can see that you are using EF6 with code first. In that case I would make use of [Table per Hierarchy](https://entityframework.net/tph) and put both `Box` and `Chest` into one table (they will be separate classes still). One (big) caveat: I have been working exclusively with EF Core for a while now, and I haven't tested this. But I have used this pattern repeatedly and it works nicely.

Your entities should look something like this:

```cs
public class WareHouse
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get;set; }

  public string Name {get;set;}

  public ICollection<Container> Containers {get;set;}
}

public abstract class Container
{
  [Key]
  public int Id {set;set;}

  public int WareHouseId {get;set;}

  [ForeignKey(nameof(WareHouseId))]
  public WareHouse WareHouse {get;set;}

  public string Name {get;set;}

  public ICollection<Product> Products {get;set;}
}

public class Box : Container
{
  // box specific stuff here
}

public class Chest : Container
{
  // chest specific stuff here
}

public class Product
{
  [Key]
  public int Id {set;set;}

  public int ContainerId {get;set;}

  [ForeignKey(nameof(ContainerId))]
  public Container Container {get;set;}  
}
```

And your context something like this:

```cs
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
  public virtual DbSet<WareHouse> WareHouses {get;set;}
  public virtual DbSet<Container> Containers {get;set;}
  public virtual DbSet<Product> Products {get;set;}

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
  {
    // puts the class name in a column, makes it human readable
    builder.Entity<Container>().Hasdiscriminator<string>("Type");

    // i don't think you need to do this, but if it doesn't work try this
    // builder.Entity<Box>().HasBaseType(typeof(Container));
    // builder.Entity<Chest>().HasBaseType(typeof(Container));
  }
}
```

Then you can get all the products from the warehouse with id=1 like this:

```cs
int warehouseId = 1;
Product[] allProducts = myContext.WareHouses
  .Where(wh => wh.Id == warehouseId)
  .SelectMany(wh => wh.Container)
  //.OfType<Box>() if you only want products in boxes
  .SelectMany(wh => wh.Products)
  .ToArray();
```

I know you said in your comment that you tend to use linq's lambda syntax, but I feel I should point out that you are doing a lot of unnecessary joins in your query syntax example. linq to entities will take care of all that for you if you have set things up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var allProducts = chestProducts.Concat(boxProducts);
```

Or you can also use Union

```
var allProducts = Enumerable.Union(chestProducts, boxProducts);
```

Comment: I'm using entity framework and I don't want to execute two queries. Probably 

var allProducts = chestProducts.AddRange(boxProducts); 

does samething

Comment: @Erdem11 then use union. It accepts IEnumerable<string> as input and will provide a query by combining both of them

Comment: @Erdem11 In your code, don't call ToList() at the end of your linq queries, then union these queries and then call ToList() on the final query.

Comment: Is that makes one query to execute on DB and returns one respond. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes. When you are writing Linq query, that query is not executed unless its called. In this case, ToList() is what is executing this query. So, if you write two Linq queries and then combine them and after combing these, you will execute that final query.

Comment: for further details, take a look at this article: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-tools/entity-framework-performance-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/